# I would like to merge 2 xlsx data frames - match and copy data to multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to copy a single row of dataframe2 to multiple rows in dataframe 1 based on postcode matching

Example dataframe1

```
    postcode   price   type
1   2000       150     A
2   2000       250     B
3   2001       350     C
4   2001       550     A
5   2001       650     B
6   2004       750     C
```

Example dataframe2

```
    postcode   lat    lon
1   2000       1.2    1.2
2   2001       1.3    1.5
3   2002       1.5    1.2
4   2003       1.6    1.5
5   2004       1.7    1.8
6   2005       1.9    1.98
7   2006       1.2    1.2
8   2007       1.3    1.5
9   2008       1.5    1.2
10   2009       1.6    1.5
11   2010       1.7    1.8
12   2011       1.9    1.98
```

Merged final dataframe according to postcode with unnecessary datas discarded from dataframe2

```
    postcode   price   type  lat    lon
1   2000       150     A     1.2    1.2
2   2000       250     B     1.2    1.2
3   2001       350     C     1.3    1.5
4   2001       550     A     1.3    1.5
5   2001       650     B     1.3    1.5
6   2004       750     C     1.9    1.98
```

Please note I do not want to use geopandas or gmaps api, I want this merged as simple as possible using an if statement or something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is very simple way of doing this. you can use pandas [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function to do so:

```
final = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='postcode')
```

returns

```
    postcode price  type    lat lon
0   2000     150    A       1.2 1.2
1   2000     250    B       1.2 1.2
2   2001     350    C       1.3 1.5
3   2001     550    A       1.3 1.5
4   2001     650    B       1.3 1.5
5   2004     750    C       1.7 1.8
```

Comment: It is not working it seems to have clipped the final dataframe. I had hundreds of postcodes but the final data frame has been clipped to only four postcodes. Please note both data frames  do not have similar number of rows.
Dataframes for download in link - 
[link]https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e806397b843f9c9fedea3f9a86e251c220200520130229/1f9a432e1aeb74a4a834b8fa1ca8ef4d20200520130249/5498a5